# TCP client doesn't read all the response on some computers

Tags: c#

I'm using this MS sample code to read response from my Apache server but on some computers, the C# app just reads the HTTP HEADER and does not read the body. for example if i put "Hello" on my index page, it only reads the header including HTTP/1.1 200 OK DATE:......

Doesn't include what i have put in the index page.

I tried to increase the size of data but there's no difference.

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);

// Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);         

// Get a client stream for reading and writing.
//  Stream stream = client.GetStream();

NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

// Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);         

// Receive the TcpServer.response.

// Buffer to store the response bytes.
data = new Byte[256];

// String to store the response ASCII representation.
String responseData = String.Empty;

// Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);         

// Close everything.
stream.Close();         
client.Close();
```

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you want to connect to an HTTP server, why don't you use [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of TcpClient?

Comment: You sohuld carefully read the contract of the [`Stream.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx) method: *An implementation is free to return fewer bytes than requested even if the end of the stream has not been reached.*

Comment: You'll want to read about the http protocol, then implement it a little better.  For instance, you should read lines until you have all of the header information.  Then, you use the content length specified in the header to read the full body of the http response.  That's the only way I know to be certain that you have retrieved everything.  Wrap your stream in a StreamReader and use ReadLine to get things started.

Comment: For the reasons Lorek mentioned you should really take Yacoub;s advice and use the Http client.  This will do the http stuff for you.  For example I think returning the header only on the first part is considered standard practice at the tcp/ip layer.  The http client handles a TON of functionality that you have just started to scrape the surface of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Read` method can return after reading part of the response. You have to loop and copy the data to `MemoryStream` until there is no more data to receive. Then decode the whole message.

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
Int32 bytes = 0;
do
{
    bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    memoryStream.Write(data, 0, bytes);
}
while (stream.DataAvailable);

responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
```

And as @YacoubMassad noticed in the comment, if you connect to an http server you can use [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Don't decode substrings like that, this can mess the encoding (think of multi-byte characters). Better copy the whole stream to a `MemoryStream` and decode *that* in a single pass.

Comment: Thank you for the response, i think it should do the trick, i'll give it a try and will get back to you, thanks again, Max

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thanks for the remark. I edited the answer.

Comment: @JakubLortz C# says it can't assign that to responseData . Anyway the solution worked out for me and thank you so much :) BTW for some reason i'm not able to use httpClient for what i need.