# C# TCP unable to get all the bytes from NetworkStream only 29200 bytes

Tags: c#, tcp, networkstream

I'm trying to read some large data from a TCP response. But I get 29200  bytes or characters. But went I debugging I get all the data if I debug step but step when calling:

```
Int32 bytes = clientStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
```

But otherwise I don't get the all of the bytes. This is my function:

```
private string SendMessage(string msg, int buffersize)
    {
        NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();

        ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes(msg);

        clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        clientStream.Flush();

        // Buffer to store the response bytes. 
        Byte[] data = new Byte[buffersize];

        // String to store the response ASCII representation. 
        String responseData = String.Empty;

        // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes. 
        Int32 bytes = clientStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

        return responseData;
    }
```

I tried using a MemoryStream like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33203184

But I don't get all the bytes either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How large is your `bufferSize` actually? Cause this is the maximum data you seem to be reading. Why not read until you read a distinct terminator to a response? Like how SMTP is implemented for instance

Comment: You're not waiting for all the data to be available.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? How many bytes do you expect instead of  29200?

Comment: If you expect specific number of bytes - then read until you get that speicific number of bytes. If you need to read until specific character\sequence appears - then read until that. If you don't know how much to read and sender doesn't specify that (for example by specifying length in the first few bytes of the message) - then you have bad protocol design and need to fix that first.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the concept of streams. If you didn't get all the data, keep reading until you do. It's a stream of data, not distinct packages.

Comment: You should add a byte count at beginning of send message so the receive end know how may bytes to read.